Using minikube how should i access services from http://localhost:80 on my PC
I am using minikube to deploy my kubernetes cluster locally. i initially run minikube start and then i install addon ingress.
After that, i apply all my yml files.
Finally i apply my ingress yml file which includes all the ingress rules.
For example:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-app
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-server
                port:
                  number: 80
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /Updates/
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /Devices/
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /api/v2/
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-api-v2
                port:
                  number: 80

Then i run minikube tunnel and i can access my app on http://192.168.x.x
Due to CORS errors, i need to run my app on http://localhost:80
I also tried to add host: localhost in rules, but the nginx would throw an error page.
How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

It looks like your Ingress rules map various URL paths to different backend services, which would seem to imply to me there's never a cross-origin call: if your browser code requests just /api/v2/test as a path-only relative URL, it should reach the app-api-v2 service, and CORS rules will never apply.  Where does the CORS concern come in?  How would you deploy this system in a real cluster, where the browser and the machines (multiple) running the various services won't be the same?

@DavidMaze Actually i get the CORS errors on app-server when opening in browser.
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/import/fetch' from origin 'http://192.168.49.2' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


Refer to this Medium Blog1 by  David Katz and Blog2 by  Stephen Biston helps to resolve your issue.

You don't have to use an Ingress. https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/
